# How can i use .not jquery with .serialize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to serialize this form without input name `lname`
Code:

```
var x = `<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> `;
var b =$(x).not("[name=lname]").serialize();
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you need to call `:not()` on the `input` elements within the form, not the form itself. The same goes for the `serialize()` method. Try this:

```js
var x = `<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> `;
var b = $(x).find('input:not([name="lname"])').serialize();
console.log(b);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) and [Attribute Not Equal Selector [name!="value"]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/):

```js
var x = `<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> `;
var b =$(x).find('input[name!=lname]').serialize();
console.log(b);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```